# sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema при переносе БД с Windows10 на Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, sqlite, миграция

Решил перенести работающий код, использующий ***SQLite*** c Windows10 на  Ubunta 16.4.  Да к тому же на ARM64  *NANOPI NEO4*.  Ну получился такой себе серверочек.  Одна программа пошла. А вот вторая, использующая ***SQLite*** - ну никак.  Говорит, что структура базы плохая.

```
pi@NanoPi-NEO4:~/py_codes/scheduler$ python3 main_scheduler.py
2021-04-01 14:51:39,165 - Sheduler.get_sheduled_tasks - INFO - Вызов с args=(<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fa5d6a960>,), kwargs={}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_scheduler.py", line 586, in <module>
    sheduled_tasks = get_sheduled_tasks(c)
  File "/home/pi/py_codes/scheduler/logger.py", line 20, in wrap_log
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main_scheduler.py", line 112, in get_sheduled_tasks
    records = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tasks_sheduled WHERE not finished').fetchall()
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (tasks_reports) - default value of column [is_handmade] is not constant
```

То есть основная ошибка:

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (TABLE_NAME) - default value of column [COLUMN_NAME] is not constant
```

Но я ничего не менял в базе. Просто  скопипастил файл.
Неужели нужна какая-то специальная миграция?

Для справки. На винде Python 3.8, а на убунте - Python 3.6
default value of column [is_handmade]  установил в False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Выдержка из документации](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> **2.1. Boolean Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
> Boolean values are stored as integers `0` (`false`) and `1` (`true`).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась как раз в **False**. Видимо на винде можно , а на убунте нет ))
Везде заменил булевы значения при создании базы по умолчания с **False**  на 0, и чтение пошло )